# Largest one among specific strings having multiple dots

Tags: ruby

I am trying to find the larger value between two decimal values or integers in specific format. For example,

- compare `2.2` with `2.1.5`. `2.2` is the larger
- compare `2.3.3` with `2.3.456`. `2.3.456` is the larger.

I cannot process it. Please suggest something to resolve this.

Comment: are these  strings? because `2.3.456` is not a valid instance of `Numeric`

Comment: Yes, right now it is in string format.

Comment: Except for `2.2`, what you have are not decimal numbers nor integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array from each version:

```
def to_version(s)
  s.split('.').map(&:to_i)
end

to_version('2.3.3')
# => [2, 3, 3]
```

Now you can compare the two results (arrays are comparable):

```
['2.2', '2.1.5'].max_by { |x| to_version(x) }
# => "2.2"
['2.3.3', '2.3.456'].max_by { |x| to_version(x) }
# => "2.3.456"
['2.13.3', '2.3.456'].max_by { |x| to_version(x) }
# => "2.13.3"
```

Comment: Working fine .. Thanks

Comment: Rubyist, see [Array#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) for an explanation of what Uri means by "arrays are comparable".

Answer (score 1):

Rubygems knows about strings as version numbers:

```
['2.13.3', '2.3.456'].map{|v| Gem::Version.new(v)}.sort 
# =>[#<Gem::Version "2.3.456">, #<Gem::Version "2.13.3">]
```

Comment: yeah, or `sort_by`